# How to update the local work branch from local master branch?

Tags: git, version-control

So I have the master and work branch. I have make a several changes in files in master branch insted of did it in inside the work branch. And now I must to push this changes from my local master branch to local work branch? The quiestion is how I can make it?

Comment: `git checkout work-branch && git merge master` would be worth a try ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting is a branch rebase. It will attempt to realign the history of `Branch-A` with `Branch-B`.

```
git checkout work-branch
git rebase master
```

And that's it, for MOST scenarios. You may be required to resolve conflicts between the two branches, but you would have had to have edited the same files in the same locations for that to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run the [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) using either [`--ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#merge-strategies-ours)  or [`--theirs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies#merge-strategies-theirs) to fix conflicts if any, where  **Ours** is the branch you are currently on and **Theirs** is the other branch that is used in your action.

For example, if you want all the changes to be merged in `work-branch` and conflicting files should be taken from `work-branch` then commands should be:

```
$ git checkout work-branch
$ git merge --strategy=ours local-master
```

Otherwise, if you want all the changes to be merged in `work-branch` and conflicting files should be taken from `local-master` then commands should be:

```
$ git checkout work-branch
$ git merge --strategy=theirs local-master
```

Answer (score 1):

The straight-forward way to synchronize the branches is to do a merge (my comment) or a rebase (Strike's answer), depending on how you want the history of the work and master branches to look afterwards. (The net effect would be the same.)

But since you were asking this question you may be looking for something different, for example correct master to a state where the changes are not visible, apply them instead to the work branch and then later merge the work branch into master, as a standard workflow would suggest.

One way to do that would be to

- branch off the current state of master into a new branch
- check out master again and reset it (hard) to the last commit prior to the changes that should have happened on the work branch (find that via `git log`)
- check out the work branch and merge the new branch containing the changes
- and finally check out master and merge the work branch which now contains the changes which had originally and erroneously been made on master.

Resetting master is only a good idea if you have not pushed master to a different repository yet.